# Mono expects BOM when wtiting output in HttpListener - Mono bug?

Tags: .net, mono, byte-order-mark, httplistener

I am trying to run a HttpListener-based server on Mono. I have examined Mono sources and it looks like Mono expects a Byte Order Mark (BOM) before writing an output in case of UTF-8 and Unicode. Here is the piece of code that I see in [SendHeaders method implementation in Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpListenerResponse.cs):

```
   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter (ms, encoding, 256);
   writer.Write ("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}\r\n", version, status_code, status_description);
   string headers_str = headers.ToStringMultiValue ();
   writer.Write (headers_str);
   writer.Flush ();
   int preamble = (encoding.CodePage == 65001) ? 3 : encoding.GetPreamble ().Length;
   if (output_stream == null)
    output_stream = context.Connection.GetResponseStream ();

   /* Assumes that the ms was at position 0 */
   ms.Position = preamble;
```

I think this is a bug because as far as I know neither Unicode not HTTP require BOM to be written before headers. Here is what [Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) article says:

> "The Unicode Standard permits the BOM in UTF-8,[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) but does not require
>   or recommend its use"

Or am I wrong? Are there any way to write UTF-8 with HttpListener in Mono?

Answer (score 1):

If you believe you have found a bug in Mono, write a unit test that passes in .NET and fails in Mono, then with that, open a bug report in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ , and then if you manage to fix the bug, propose a pull request to http://github.com/mono/mono referencing the bug number you created and adding your unit test to the test suite.